# How to apply stream management in xmpp android

Tags: android, xmpp

I have started with one to one chat in android using xmpp and ejabbered, ***the issue that I am facing is that whenever we get sudden fluctuation in network and when the network is lost, the further messages for the user are lost,** as the server still considers that user online and does not store the user's messages in offline table, so to overcome that I have applied stream management setting to the "XMPPTCPConnection" in my code as well as server, the code for the same is below

```
connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
connection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);
connection.setPreferredResumptionTime(10);
```

Now I am aware that only this can not prevent the message loss, we need to apply our own logic for that.
So if anyone knows the proper way of preventing the message loss using XMPP stream management, please guide me.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `PingManager` both client side and server side. for more details please check this link https://ramzandroidarchive.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/handling-connection-break-issue-in-smack-4-1/